# D&D dice program (without loop)

Tags: python, dice

I'm supposed to write a program to roll a dice five times but I can't have any redundancies and I can't use any kind of loops.
I'll paste here the text from the exercise.
"Build a python application so that it prompts the user to enter the number of sides the dice will have (dungeons and dragons style dice!)
After this, it will then roll the dice with that many sides five times and output all five outcomes to the user
The rolling the dice five times will require five repeated blocks of code – remove this redundancy by using a user defined function to roll the dice

Can anyone help me?

```
import random

def main():

    diceType = int(input("Enter how many sides the dices will have: "))

    diceRoll1 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll2 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll3 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll4 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll5 = random.randint(1,diceType)

    print("The dices read", diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5)

main()
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this without loops?

Comment: It Is a challenge from class.

Comment: Are you supposed to use the `itertools` module?

Comment: it sounds like you need a list comprehension here

Comment: Not sure you're explaining the problem well enough. If you are this is a silly challenge.

Comment: Depending on how you define "any kind of loops" and redundancy, this task is somewhere between trivial and impossible.

Comment: The purpose of this challenge is to use a user call function. We didn't learn itertools modules or lists or loops yet. I know its terrible, but needs to be that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "redundancy"?

Comment: Most challenges like this specify what you *can* use; are you supposed to be exercising recursion, for example?

Comment: For example of redundancy, these lines over here are redundancies in my code:

Comment: diceRoll1 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll2 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll3 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll4 = random.randint(1,diceType)
    diceRoll5 = random.randint(1,diceType)

Comment: I need to fix that but I don't know how.

Comment: Could it be that you have misunderstood the task and that your instructor is expecting a more complicated function to generate the throw of a die and that you are not allowed to repeat or loop that code, but that it is fine to call a function repeatedly five times? That makes a whole lot more sense from a learning perspective.

Comment: JohanL, you are right! I supose that I can use a call function repeatedly five times. I'll paste the text from exercise here just to clarify.

Comment: Build a python application so that it prompts the user to enter the number of sides the dice will have (dungeons and dragons style dice!)
After this, it will then roll the dice with that many sides five times and output all five outcomes to the user
The rolling the dice five times will require five repeated blocks of code – remove this redundancy by using a user defined function to roll the dice

Answer (score 2):

Note : This is a terrible way to do it. The purpose of loops is to remove redundancy. Without any kind of loop, all solutions would be hacky, difficult to read and probably inefficient.

```
import random

def roll5(diceType, remaining_roll=5):

    if remaining_roll == 0:
        return []

    retval = roll5(diceType, remaining_roll - 1)
    retval.append(random.randint(1,diceType))
    return retval

diceType = int(input("Enter how many sides the dices will have: "))

diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5 = roll5(diceType)
print("The dices read", diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5)
```

Comment: While this _may_ be a valid solution, depending on who is judging, I would argue that a recursive function is a kind of loop. Languages with tail call optimization can make code with recursive calls identical to code with a loop.

Comment: Thanks Seljuk! The point here is that the program don't need to be efficient or  easier to read. Its for learning purposes.

Comment: @JohanL Don't confuse "loop" with "repetition"; a loop is a syntactic construct in a given language for repeated execution of a block of code.

Comment: @chepner It is a valid point but it requires that you limit "any kind of loop" to be a loop according to the normal definition used in software. Maybe that is reasonable, though. But "any kind of..." is rather far-reaching.

Comment: I would say that the list of variables is redundant. Maybe use `print("The dices read", *roll5(diceType))` instead of the last two lines?

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension list

```
import random
randomList = [random.randint(1,diceType) for _ in range(5)]
diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5 = randomList
```

Comment: I would say this still counts as using a loop, a list comprehension is just a shortcut to populate a list using a for loop

Comment: @BigGerman It depends on what the OP refers to loop, but yes, in the bytecode there is a loop

Comment: Yeah, its considered a loop. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `itertools` module.

```
>>> from itertools import islice, imap, repeat
>>> from random import randint
>>> diceType = 5
>>> list(islice(imap(random.randint, repeat(1), repeat(diceType)), 5))
[5, 5, 4, 5, 4]
```

`repeat` creates infinite sequences of 1s and `diceType`s. `imap` creates an infinite sequence of the result of calling `randint(1, diceType)` (each call pulls the next value of `repeat(1)` and `repeat(diceType)` as an argument. `islice` makes a finite iterator that takes only the first 5 elements of the infinite sequence, and `list` actually takes the values from the finite iterator.

Along the same lines, without using `itertools`, is the following (using Python 2's version of `map` for simplicity):

```
map(lambda f: f(1, diceType), [randint]*5)
```

This creates a list with 5 separate references to `randint`, then maps a function that calls its arguments on 1 and `diceType` over that list.

(Actually, the `itertools` version can be simplified using that same approach:

```
list(islice(map(lambda f: f(1, diceType), repeat(randint)), 5))
```

)

Comment: Thanks chepner! That's great! But I can't use list because it wasn't taught yet. :-(

Comment: I can't wait to hear what your teacher has in mind if you can't use loops or lists.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I can't use any loops, I would do this with a list to keep track of what has and hasn't been used.

```
diceType = int(input("Enter how many sides the dices will have: "))
lyst = range(1,diceType+1)

diceRoll1 = random.choice(lyst)
lyst.remove(diceRoll1)
diceRoll2 = random.choice(lyst)
lyst.remove(diceRoll2)
diceRoll3 = random.choice(lyst)
lyst.remove(diceRoll3)
diceRoll4 = random.choice(lyst)
lyst.remove(diceRoll4)
diceRoll5 = random.choice(lyst)
lyst.remove(diceRoll5)

print("The dices read", diceRoll1, diceRoll2, diceRoll3, diceRoll4, diceRoll5)
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but I like how readable it is. You chose something from the list then remove it. And then do that 4 more times.

Comment: Thank you Julie! Unfortunately I suppose that I can't use lyst because its wasn't taugh yet.